# Does all BLHELI_32 ESC supports bi-directional rotation?

Tags: esc

Hello im new to drone stuff, im just wondering if any BLHELI_32 is compatible with bidirectional rotation? since blheli 32 software supports bidirectional rotation is it safe to assume that all blheli32 boards can do it? Was planning to use an ESC as a motor driver and an arduino as the controller.

Im getting this [ESC from hakrc](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08B8D14PV) although it does not advertise as bidirectional as i have not seen a 4in1 drone esc that advertized its rotation (i assumed that this is common knowledge for in the drone community? ), was hoping that it probably can :slight_smile:

Comment: I believe so, but I'm not absolutely sure... AFAIK all BLHELI_32 ESCs should support that, as it's a core feature in the firmware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse rotation for 'turtle mode' or 'flip after crash' has been around for a good few years, so I'd guess that anything you buy these days will support it.